# Event listeners are not working but there is no error

Tags: javascript, html

I have an event listener listening to the submission of form which will be sent to firebase auth. A few hours ago, it was working fine. But suddenly, it just stopped. No error nothing. No event listeners were working. I restarted vs code and my computer. Where event listeners were defined -

```
import { smoothScroll } from './animations.js';
import { signup, logout } from './auth.js';

smoothScroll();

// Elements
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#signup-form');
const logoutBtn = document.querySelector('#logout-btn');

console.log(signupForm);

signupForm.addEventListener('submit', signup);
logoutBtn.addEventListener('click', logout);
```

Actual functions -

```
export function signup(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('Sugb');

    // User info
    const email = signupForm['email'].value;
    const password = signupForm['password'].value;

    // Sign up
    auth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((cred) => {
            document.querySelector('.alert').classList.add('alert--show');

            document.querySelector('.alert').textContent = 'User signed up';

            loginState = true;

            signupForm.reset();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            document
                .querySelector('.alert')
                .classList.remove('alert-success')
                .add('alert-danger')
                .add('alert--show');

            document.querySelector('.alert').textContent = error.message;
        });
}

export function logout(e) {
    console.log('Logout');
    alert('Logout');
}
```

Through a bit of debugging I found out that my functions were not getting called. This is the github repo https://github.com/akashshyamdev/doubt1 in case you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is that `#signup-form` and/or `#logout-btn` are not present during `querySelector()`.

Comment: I logged the values of that into the console. They are getting selected

Comment: Set up your console so it does not clear itself on form submissions. Find the error

Comment: On form submissions the page reloads. That cant be changed by the console

Answer (score 0):

Since the signup form is present, when you add the event listener, but the event callback function is not called, I assume you changed the form after the event listener addition.

For this you must delegate the event to an element that is always there, typically the `document`. As the MDN doc says about the [submit_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) that it bubbles up, we can do this

Instead of
`signupForm.addEventListener('submit', signup);`

do this

```
document.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('#signup-form')) {
    return signup(e);
  }
  return false;
});
```